# ob_start() works fine in local but giving error on hosting

Tags: php, gzip, ob-start

I am using PHP addressbook for an web application with some additional features. Everything works fine when I tested it in my local machine using Xampp but when I hosted it in a online webserver it throws the following error message:

> [ref.outcontrol]: output handler
>   'ob_gzhandler' cannot be used twice in .../dbconnect.php on line 27

... and the page is not showing anything its just an empty page.

```
if(   ini_get('zlib.output_compression') != 1
   && isset($compression_level) 
   && $compression_level > 0) {
  ini_set('zlib.output_compression_level', $compression_level);
  ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue. My gzip compressor is in off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome this just put a if check like this before adding it

```
    if (!in_array('ob_gzhandler', ob_list_handlers())) {
        ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
    } else {
        ob_start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It says:

> output handler 'ob_gzhandler' cannot be used twice in
>   .../dbconnect.php

You **can not** call ob_start('ob_gzhandler') **more than once** in your code.